# JS normalizr how to add unrelated key to entities

Tags: javascript, redux, normalizr

I  want to normalize my data with [`normalizr`](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr). The problem is that I have in my data one key (`teams`) that it does not have a  relationship with the other data.

For example:

```
const data = {
   programs: [{
       id: 1,
       label: 'Program one',
       products: [{
           id: 1,
           label: 'Product one',
           releases: [{
             id: 1,
             label: 'Release one',
           }]
         }
       ]
     }
   ],
   teams: [{
       id: 1,
       value: 1,
       label: 'Team one',
     }
   ]
 }
```

And my schema:

```
  const release = new schema.Entity('releases');

  const product = new schema.Entity('products', {
    releases: [release]
  });

  const program = new schema.Entity('programs', {
    products: [product],
  });

  normalize(data, [program]);
```

How can I also add the teams to the entities object that generated by `normalizr`? So the results need to be:

```
{
  entities: {
     products: {},
     programs: {},
     releases: {},
     teams: []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`normalizr` can handle disjoint sets of data if you tell it the encompassing schema of your data:

```js
const release = new schema.Entity('releases');

const product = new schema.Entity('products', {
  releases: [release]
});

const program = new schema.Entity('programs', {
  products: [product],
});

// add team entity
const team = new schema.Entity('teams');

// the encompassing schema
const dataschema = {
  programs: [program],
  teams: [team]
}

// normalize
normalize(data, dataschema);

// or omit dataschema definition and pass in directly
normalize(data, {
    programs: [program],
    teams: [team]
});
```

will result in:

*Notice that the `result` object now consists of two arrays with the keys of your top-level entities.*

```
{
    entities: {
        releases: {
            1: {
                id: 1,
                label: "Release one"
            }
        },
        products: {
            1: {
                id: 1,
                label: "Product one",
                releases: [1]
            }
        },
        programs: {
            1: {
                id: 1,
                label: "Program one",
                products: [1]
            }
        },
        teams: {
            1: {
                id: 1,
                value: 1,
                label: "Team one"
            }
        }
    },
    result: {
        programs: [1],
        teams: [1]
    }
}
```